# How to pause a method until a condition is true then resume

Tags: objective-c

Upon a button being pressed, i would like to begin tracking whether other buttons are being pressed.

Right now this is how i am attempting to do like this:

```
while(true)
{
   if button1pressedbool and button2pressedbool
   {
      break
   }
   usleep(20000)
}

[self doMethodNowThatButtons1&2arePressed]
```

I need for the user to select another button before proceeding in this method, is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**  User...'s answer looks correct, does anybody have an example code of how to use and check a selector as he suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much better way to do this.

Set button1 tag to 0 and button2 tag to 1.

```
button1.tag = 0;
button2.tag = 1;
```

Then set the action for both buttons for the same selector.

In that method, check the tag of the button (use sender).  If the tag == 0 set a `BOOL` button1Pressed to `YES`.  Do the same for the other button.

This way, regardless of which button you pressed first, when `button1Pressed == YES && button2Pressed == YES` you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry I am new to OBJ-c, how do i set an action for the button?

Comment: @objectivelyC https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents: